# Processar XML de NFe em Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, nfe

Tenho o seguinte código que visa buscar um determinado nó de um XML de Nota Fiscal Eletrônica, mas sem sucesso. Testei com outros XMLs e funcionou.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("nfe.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()
nodefind = doc.find('NFe/infNFE/ide/cUF')
print nodefind.attrib
print nodefind.text
```

Abaixo o erro que está retornando:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/scob/Documents/NFE_to_CSV3.py in <module>()
      4 doc = tree.getroot()
      5 nodefind = doc.find('NFe/infNFE/ide/cUF')
----> 6 print nodefind.attrib
      7 print nodefind.text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Esse erro se dá pois ele não acha o caminho que estou procurando. Se eu printar a variável doc, que é o root tenho:

```
In [17]: print doc
<Element 'nfeProc' at 0x7f1fd57ba310>
```

Existem diferenças entre XMLs? Ou existe algum atributo nesse XML que essa biblioteca do python não consegue capturar?

Aqui está o XML:

```html
<nfeProc versao='3.10' xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'><NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <infNFe Id="NFe33160500333019000150550000000382921947944521" versao="3.10">
    <ide>
      <cUF>33</cUF>
      <cNF>94794452</cNF>
      <natOp>VENDA F/E</natOp>
      <indPag>0</indPag>
      <mod>55</mod>
      <serie>0</serie>
      <nNF>38292</nNF>
      <dhEmi>2016-05-31T00:00:00-03:00</dhEmi>
      <dhSaiEnt>2016-05-31T15:39:15-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
      <tpNF>1</tpNF>
      <idDest>2</idDest>
      <cMunFG>3304557</cMunFG>
      <tpImp>1</tpImp>
      <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
      <cDV>1</cDV>
      <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
      <finNFe>1</finNFe>
      <indFinal>1</indFinal>
      <indPres>1</indPres>
      <procEmi>0</procEmi>
      <verProc>3.10</verProc>
    </ide>
    <emit>
      <CNPJ>00333019000150</CNPJ>
      <xNome>BLABLABLABLA</xNome>
      <xFant>BLUBLUBLU</xFant>
      <enderEmit>
        <xLgr>RUA NAIR 03 E COMPL RUA SGT. AQUINO 38</xLgr>
        <nro>S/N</nro>
        <xBairro>OLARIA</xBairro>
        <cMun>3304557</cMun>
        <xMun>RIO DE JANEIRO</xMun>
        <UF>RJ</UF>
        <CEP>21021600</CEP>
        <cPais>1058</cPais>
        <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
        <fone>21428100</fone>
      </enderEmit>
      <IE>85682938</IE>
      <CRT>2</CRT>
    </emit>
    <dest>
      <CPF>123123123123</CPF>
      <xNome>JOSE DAS COUVES</xNome>
      <enderDest>
        <xLgr>RUA PRINCESA IZABEL</xLgr>
        <nro>92</nro>
        <xBairro>ALVORADA</xBairro>
        <cMun>3106705</cMun>
        <xMun>BETIM</xMun>
        <UF>MG</UF>
        <CEP>32687058</CEP>
        <cPais>1058</cPais>
        <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
        <fone>35317845</fone>
      </enderDest>
      <indIEDest>2</indIEDest>
      <email>@hehe.com.br</email>
    </dest>
    <det nItem="1">
      <prod>
        <cProd>1120526P20</cProd>
        <cEAN>9986350009317</cEAN>
        <xProd>PNEU 205/55R16 91W PHANTM (PN19507)</xProd>
        <NCM>40111000</NCM>
        <CFOP>6404</CFOP>
        <uCom>UN</uCom>
        <qCom>1.00</qCom>
        <vUnCom>346.57</vUnCom>
        <vProd>346.57</vProd>
        <cEANTrib>9986350009317</cEANTrib>
        <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
        <qTrib>1.00</qTrib>
        <vUnTrib>346.57</vUnTrib>
        <indTot>1</indTot>
      </prod>
      <imposto>
        <ICMS>
          <ICMS60>
            <orig>0</orig>
            <CST>60</CST>
            <vBCSTRet>346.57</vBCSTRet>
            <vICMSSTRet>0.00</vICMSSTRet>
          </ICMS60>
        </ICMS>
        <PIS>
          <PISAliq>
            <CST>01</CST>
            <vBC>346.57</vBC>
            <pPIS>1.65</pPIS>
            <vPIS>5.72</vPIS>
          </PISAliq>
        </PIS>
        <COFINS>
          <COFINSAliq>
            <CST>01</CST>
            <vBC>346.57</vBC>
            <pCOFINS>7.60</pCOFINS>
            <vCOFINS>26.34</vCOFINS>
          </COFINSAliq>
        </COFINS>
      </imposto>
    </det>
    <total>
      <ICMSTot>
        <vBC>0.00</vBC>
        <vICMS>0.00</vICMS>
        <vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
        <vBCST>0.00</vBCST>
        <vST>0.00</vST>
        <vProd>346.57</vProd>
        <vFrete>0.00</vFrete>
        <vSeg>0.00</vSeg>
        <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
        <vII>0.00</vII>
        <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
        <vPIS>5.72</vPIS>
        <vCOFINS>26.34</vCOFINS>
        <vOutro>0.00</vOutro>
        <vNF>346.57</vNF>
        <vTotTrib>0.00</vTotTrib>
      </ICMSTot>
    </total>
    <transp>
      <modFrete>0</modFrete>
      <transporta>
        <CNPJ>34028316000294</CNPJ>
        <xNome>EMPRESA BRASILEIRA DE CORREIOS E TELEGRAFOS</xNome>
        <IE>81613524</IE>
        <xEnder>AV PRESIDENTE VARGAS 3077</xEnder>
        <xMun>RIO DE JANEIRO</xMun>
        <UF>RJ</UF>
      </transporta>
      <vol>
        <qVol>1</qVol>
        <esp>PNEU</esp>
        <marca>PIRELLI</marca>
        <nVol>1</nVol>
      </vol>
    </transp>
    <cobr />
    <infAdic>
      <infCpl>VALOR APROXIMADO DOS TRIBUTOS R$ 130,55 FONTE IBPT. IMPOSTO RETIDO POR SUBSTITUICAO TRIBUTARIA CONFORME RICMS-RJ,LIVRO II PROCON-RJ RUA DA AJUDA, 05 SUBSOLO - CENTRO - TEL 151 CODECON - RUA DA ALFANDEGA, 8 TERREO - CENTRO - RJ. - ALERJ - TEL 08002827060</infCpl>
    </infAdic>
  </infNFe>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#NFe33160500333019000150550000000382921947944521">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>kWGw/UdKxiZ5mhRV4B6NgVXGM7w=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>IsWN2a98EOTMbjvg2Ab4oKIKuBxLhpZhY8n2HCg0sQrBQgK/NFBQ49IbdFrgQdanTRPdxiH6H7iV5HDA756AY5HeoSqRQ7NC929GOWU3ZIo56QoeGrJgiFq1O6SaD8DZO890elY/vqORGBLA5C1GDjUfxUoUexh04BkoWjexK9h2GKpc2ErOs3JFL9DBBaI/TiPAKGNdmV/VhWlcchVVr03y4ENp3Dwf/lhjbeiSTHoILN8h1MGm55WyOAOIdOVYd8s4NeIBLY1ffTMdJlCIJ6/asux6MUQhxUVPfbw+rZrxPm8A+Ul5ZR7dxa3GmXDslp1/vSbYt7uK+lddvZcfRQ==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</NFe><protNFe versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <infProt>
    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
    <verAplic>SVRS201605230958</verAplic>
    <chNFe>33160500333019000150550000000382921947944521</chNFe>
    <dhRecbto>2016-05-31T15:39:47-03:00</dhRecbto>
    <nProt>333160070971725</nProt>
    <digVal>kWGw/UdKxiZ5mhRV4B6NgVXGM7w=</digVal>
    <cStat>100</cStat>
    <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
  </infProt>
</protNFe></nfeProc>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá? Que python usa, 2.x ou 3.x?

Comment: Será que é por duas vezes o `xmls`?

Comment: Acabei de editar com o erro. O Python é 2.7.11+.
Não entendi seu segundo comentário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema é ocasionado porque na linha`doc.find('NFe/infNFE/ide/cUF')` retorna None, e None não tem o atributo "attrib".

Eu já tive alguns problemas com o lxml, e como eu prefiro trabalhar com dicionários eu passei a usar o módulo xmltodict (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict), Veja o exemplo:

```
import xmltodict

with open("nfe.xml") as arquivo:

    doc = xmltodict.parse(arquivo)
    print doc["nfeProc"]["NFe"]["infNFe"]["ide"]["cUF"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa adicionar o namespace na string de busca da função find. Então altere:

```
nodefind = doc.find('NFe/infNFE/ide/cUF')
```

por:

```
nodefind = doc.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}NFe/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}infNFe/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}ide/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}cUF')
```

Ficando assim:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> tree = ET.parse("nfe.xml")
>>> doc = tree.getroot()
>>> nodefind = doc.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}NFe/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}infNFe/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}ide/{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}cUF')
>>> print nodefind.attrib
{}
>>> print nodefind.text
33
```

Answer (score -2):

Sei que já faz bastante tempo, mas afim de ajudar outros segue um bloco de código que busca qualquer informação na estrutura do XML passando apenas o noPai e a tag

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(doc.xml) root = tree.getroot() prefix =
"{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}"
 
for info in root.findall('.//{}ide'.format(prefix)):
    return info.find(prefix + cUF).text
```